# Running Total of Running Total in DAX

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I need a metric which calculates "Running Total of Running Total" like

[image]

Calculating running total is fine, but I could not figured it out how to calculate "Running Total of Running Total"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you using to calculate the Running Total? What measures are you currently using?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a running total as a [calculated column or measure](https://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/running-total-techniques-in-dax/). Regardless of the method you choose the logic will be similar. Since you have not provided much detail on how you have things setup. My answer below is based on creating two calculated columns.

First create a calculated column called "Running Total"

```
=CALCULATE(
 SUM(Transactions[actual]),
 All(Transactions),
 Transactions[month]<=EARLIER(Transactions[month])
)
```

Next create a calculated column that uses the column created above called "Running Total of Running Total"

```
=CALCULATE(
SUM(Transactions[Running Total]),
All(Transactions),
Transactions[month]<=EARLIER(Transactions[month])
)
```

Comment: I am in the same dilemma as the OP and need to create a running total of a calculated field but the SUM Dax Formula keeps telling me that my argument must be a column reference, which i take it that it cannot be a calculated field?

Comment: I just tried and this is the error it gives 

"Calculation error in measure 'Date'[cumu of cumu]: The SUM function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 1."